# request new password link does not work if not logged in

Tags: users

When anonymous user comes to the site, the login block offers a link to "Request new password".  This returns the user to the home page with no action happening.  If a user is logged in, using the same link brings one to the reset password by email link.

What I want is a form taking username and returning email address with a link to the one time password change.

Comment: I suppose this is not very secure, but then why is it in the login block?

Comment: what url does the "Request new password" link in the block point to?

Comment: It points to user/password

Answer (score 0):

Drupal 7's core handling of password reset can seem a bit cumbersome, since it uses a one-time link to a one-time login reset page which can be confusing to users. I recommend using the [Simple Password Reset module](https://www.drupal.org/project/simple_pass_reset) which streamlines the process and makes it very easy for users. It works great right out of the box.

Comment: I am not sure this helps, because the user has to be logged in to get to his profile edit form.  What about the more likely case that the user cannot remember her password, and so is not logged in when tgrying to get a new password?

Comment: @WilliamWanklyn if you look at the module's URL in my answer, you will see a screengarb of that exact feature... this module also simplifies the reset process by eliminating the need for the 1-time login page, it simply sends out a 1-time link which takes user to the password reset seen in the screengrab, then updates and logs the user in. Simple and easy!

Comment: @WilliamWanklyn did you get it resolved? If yes, please share!